# Login not working with md5

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, md5

Ok, so I try to log-in to my site, but it tells me the username is wrong, I previously used MD5 with a salt for secure passwords, but now I just use plain MD5, so I removed the salt function. Now it won't let me log in?

```
<?php

session_start();

$Info['sqlhost'] = ".\SQLEXPRESS";
$Info['sqluser'] = "sa";
$Info['sqlpass'] = "******";
$Info['sqldb'] = "Account";

$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=$Info[sqlhost];Database=$Info[sqldb];", $Info['sqluser'], $Info['sqlpass']);

$postData['user'] = sql_clean($_POST['user']);
$postData['pass'] = MD5(sql_clean($_POST['pass']));
$postData['page'] = $_POST['page'];
$postData['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$stmt = odbc_prepare($connection, "SELECT * FROM Account..tAccounts WHERE sUsername = ?");
$exec = odbc_execute($stmt, array($postData['user']));

if($stmt)
{
    $sqlData = odbc_fetch_array($stmt);
    $userData['sUsername'] = $sqlData['sUsername'];
    $userData['sUserPass'] = $sqlData['sUserPass'];
    $userData['sIP'] = $sqlData['sIP'];

    if(odbc_num_rows($stmt) != 1)
    {
        header('Location: index.php?failed=1337');
        exit();
    }elseif (MD5($postData['pass']) == $userData['sUserPass'])
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $userData['sUsername'];
        header("Location:  $postData[page]");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: '. $postData['page'] .'?failed=1337');
        exit();
    }
}
else
{
    die('Query Failed');
}


function sql_clean($str) {

$characters = array('^', '°', '!', '"', '²', '§', '³', '$', '%', '&', '/', '{', '(', '[', ')', ']', '=', '}', '?', '\'', '´', '`', '€', '*', '+', '~', '#', "'", '<', '>', '|', 'µ', ';');
$replace=array('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '');

return str_replace($characters,$replace,$str);

}

odbc_close($connection);



?>
```

The URL just returns with ?failed=1337 and nothing else happens.

Comment: *"Login not working with md5"* - Call it a *blessing in disguise*. You shouldn't be using that old hasher; it's old and broken. I recommend you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Account..tAccounts` <= pseudo code?

Comment: I would be using SHA2 if it was my way, but it's not.

Comment: What do you mean by "but it's not"? You have no choice "but" to use that? Say it ain't so. *"I previously used MD5 with a salt for secure passwords, but now I just use plain MD5, so I removed the salt function."* Well now, you're going to have to. No salt, no sauce. They need to match. If passwords were stored with the salt, then you're out of luck without it.

Comment: Well it would require redoing a lot more than this, changing the database passwords (which already have public members registered.) Rewriting the registration, control panel, and more. So I would like to stick with MD5 for the time being.

Comment: Passwords are not stored with a salt, it's from a different database, the registration does not salt the passwords. There is no salt at all anymore.

Comment: There is a way to convert MD5 to `password_hash()` if you Google it. You'll spend less time doing that or getting/forcing your users to reset their passwords with a safer hashing method. If and when your DB gets compromised, you'd of wished you used a safer algo to start with. I'm giving you *the right time of day* here. Have a look at http://daveismyname.com/login-and-registration-system-with-php-bp it's PDO with `password_hash()`.

Comment: Now, what I think may be an issue is that you're using `sql_clean()` on the MD5 password input. This `$postData['pass'] = MD5(sql_clean($_POST['pass']));` and then rehashing with `elseif (MD5($postData['pass'])`, which seems to be another issue. You shouldn't be using MD5 with `$postData['pass'] = MD5(sql_clean($_POST['pass']));` but on DB check only. You are hashing twice.

Comment: I understand, and appreciate it, but I'm not very worried about a database compromise, this is more for fun than anything, only a small range of users are expected as well. I understand that security is a concern, but we also use SQLSRV (Which yes, I know, it's slower than odbc, but it doesn't matter to me, I'm experimenting more than anything.)

If you could help me with the problem I asked about, that would be great. :)

Comment: Alright, I understand and you're welcome. Check my previous comment if you haven't seen it, ^^^ just above yours.

Comment: Oh, thank you, although I just attempted to fix it, not sure if I even did it right to be honest... 
I removed: $postData['pass'] = MD5(sql_clean($_POST['pass']));

And it does the same thing :/

Comment: Are both your form elements named? I.e.: `name="pass"`

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand, I'm self-taught, meaning my knowledge is scattered, and I don't know all the terms

Comment: In your HTML form. It should look something like `<form action="file.php" method="post">` then `Password: <input type="password" name="pass">` do you have that? `name="pass"` is an most important part as well as the form's method. Same thing for the username.

Comment: oh, yea, here: 

 <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="infopanel">
   </br>
   </br>
   </br>
   </br>
   <div id="info">
     <form action="login.php" method="post">
             <input type="text" class="textbox" style="color: #000" name="user" placeholder="Username"/>
             <input type="password" class="textbox"  style="color: #000" name="pass" placeholder="******"/>
             <input type="hidden" name="page" value="/Mall/?failed=1337?failed=1337?failed=1337">
             <input type="submit" class="button"  value="Login" id="btnLogin"/>
            </form>    </div>
  </div>

Comment: Hard for me to say at this point. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: No errors :/

I didn't remove the PostData from the elseif statement, did I remove the right one?

Comment: Try changing `$postData['pass'] = MD5(sql_clean($_POST['pass']));` to `$password = $_POST['pass'];` 
then changing to `elseif (MD5($password) == $userData['sUserPass'])`

Comment: or `$password = md5($_POST['pass'])` and `elseif (($password) == $userData['sUserPass'])` - Am out of ideas beyond that. Plus make sure your column is long enough to accomodate the hash.